# django + varnish caching not being stored due to csrf tokens

Tags: django, caching, csrf, varnish

I have a login form on my homepage.  This is causing a csrf token to be set and this is meaning that my page is not being stored in the varnish cache.

How should I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two main courses: either give up using varnish to cache the page, or give up having a login form on the page. The CSRF token (which you don't want to lose) will prevent you from successfully caching the page in varnish; even if you take it into account, you're going to end up with a copy of the page for every single person visiting, which defeats the purpose of using varnish.

A solution halfway between the two is to cache the page without login form in varnish, and then insert the login form using Javascript. The main page will be cached, and you should be able to make the login form (pulled via AJAX) fast enough to not cause you problems. Another possible solution would involve putting the login form in an IFRAME, although that complicates matters yet further since you'd have to have something in the response to logging in which worked with Javascript in the main page (that included the IFRAME in the first place) to reload it suitably.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I was thinking about using esi to solve this too, but I think I may try out the js solution first. My login form is actually in a light box iframe already it is some forms I have in js templates that seem to be causing the crsf token to be set so making those external should be a quick thing to try. Thanks again, I will post later to share how I got on.

Comment: Update: the issue was two fold.  A crsf token was being set buy an external app I was using which blocked caching in varnish.  Once I isolated that I found that varnish was still not caching.  In the #varnish irc channel I was told that when you are using the Authorization header varnish skips checks and never caches by default.